# why does this if statement give my a ValueError?

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I'm trying to iterate over a numpy 2d array and check where the values 1,2 and 3 occur in the array, but i receive a value error, because numpy states that it's ambiguous. What is the best way to fix this problem?

```py
for x in range(row):
        for y in range(row):
            if grid[x,y] == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (x * distance, y * distance, distance, distance))
            elif grid[x,y] == 2:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (x * distance, y * distance, distance, distance))
            elif  grid[x,y] == 3:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (x * distance, y * distance, distance, distance))
```

```
 if grid[x,y] == 1:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you show your 2d array?

Comment: `def generateGrid(self):
        grid = np.zeros((20,20))
        try:
            for c,i in enumerate(self.snake.body):
                if c == 0:
                    #2 is head
                    grid[i.x ,i.y] = 2
                else:
                    #1 is body
                    grid[i.x, i.y] = 1
        except:
            pass
            #is food
        grid[self.food.x, self.food.y] = 3
        return grid

Comment: Please `print(grid)` and paste the output.

Comment: [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

Comment: Replace `grid[i.x, i.y]` to `grid[i.x][ i.y]` in `generateGrid` function.

Comment: Same has been updated in answer. Accept it if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your `generateGrid` function, shown in comments,

Replace `grid[i.x, i.y]` to `grid[i.x][ i.y]` in `generateGrid` function.

This has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grid[x][y]` instead of grid[x,y]

Comment: What's there in grid[1][1] ? Is it a single value or an array ?

Comment: mh it gives an index error! 
 print(grid[1,1])
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1